# In electrolysis, does voltage or amperage produce more gas?

Tags: electrolysis

I'm trying to produce a large amount of brown's gas, and I'm wondering if higher voltage or amperage will split the water faster.

Comment: What gas do you want formed? If you increase the voltage, you run the risk of electrolysis of other species and therefore of obtaining a mixture of products.
the greater the intensity and the greater the number of electrons, therefore the more products you form

Comment: I'm making brown's gas, a mix of h2 and o2. I'm just doing electrolysis of salt water, and I want to produce a lot of gas quickly.

Comment: Too high voltage, and/or using concentrated salt solution would produce also the third gas – chlorine.

Comment: Note that the voltage and current are not independent. You need a particular voltage for expected current, that is determined by used electrolyte and geometry of electrolytic cell. Too soft source of high voltage cannot provide sufficient current and a hard source of too low voltage cannot provide it either.

Answer (score 0):

The chemical yield in an electrolysis is proportional to the amperage. Increasing the voltage is no use. It will only increase the production of heat. But it is often necessary to increase the voltage to increase the amperage. A good way of increasing the amperage without increasing the voltage is to decrease the distance between the electrodes, and increasing the surfaces of the electrodes.